# iPhone What is the name of the Layer of the default iPhone Dialing App?

Tags: iphone

There are two screens = my app screen and default iPhone Dialing App screen.
I want to access the layer of the iPhone Dialing App from my app code.
What is the name of the layer of the iPhone Dialing App ?
this is my code =

CALayer *layer;

layer = self.view.layer;

Comment: This layer is not in the address space of your app's process.

Comment: You can't access anything outside your app's sandbox. What you are asking for is not possible. However, since you want to get the layer, you are probably looking for some sort of visual effect. Why not rephrase your question to ask what you actually want to achieve, instead of a specific way you (wrongly) think it may be done?

Comment: @jrturton suggestion is a good one. There is probably a way to do whatever you are trying to do taking an alternative route, since you can not access external domains views nor layers.